# Do we need "on" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

In Steve Jobs's biography by Walter Isaacson, the author writes:

> ...another health issue that became increasingly problematic, one that
> medical researchers didn't focus on as rigorously ***as they did*** cancer
> or pain.

I feel like you need an additional **on** after ***they did***:

> focus on as rigorously as they did ***on*** cancer.

It wouldn't be necessary if there were no ***they did*** but maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Well "on" isn't *needed*, in that the meaning is perfectly clear without it, but in my opinion the sentence sounds better with it.

Comment: Please don't write answers in comments; they are harmful to our site. Doing
so bypasses our community-moderated quality measures by not permitting
community editing or paired up- and down-voting available on comments, as
well as having [other problems detailed on
meta](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1644/3171). Comments 
are for clarifying and improving the question; please don't use them for
other purposes.

Comment: Why do you think that *on* is required to be repeated in this particular sentence? I can think of other situations where words are not repeated, yet they are not needed to be.

Comment: What comes before the elipsis?

Comment: @tchrist Some things in English can only be opinion based. This is a great example of that, and unfortunately this site does not seen to know that. What a pity.

Answer (score 1):

I would always edit examples of this sort to include “on”, although it is not grammatically essential. Doing so keeps the reader’s attention on the original mention of focussing.

Comment: I would too. But where is the support for 'it is not grammatically essential'? I can't write an 'answer' here as I can only put opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly don't need any further "on" after the first one. Consider it to be there but elided - which is normal idiomatic English.

My preferred way of writing it would be:

*...one on which medical researches did not focus as they did (on) cancer or pain*.